# How do I pass multiple arguments to a Ruby method using |

Tags: ruby, opengl

I saw the way it gets arguments this method and wanted to know how to replicate it.

Ruby/OpenGL:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
```

I tried with this:

```
def my_method(*args)
    puts args
end
my_method(0 | 1) #=> 1
```

But it does not work. Thanks for read!

[Link](https://github.com/lazyatom/ruby-opengl/blob/master/examples/NeHe/nehe_lesson02.rb#L58) to see the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|` is a [bit-OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) argument. `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` and `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` are integer constants (`0x00004000` and `0x00000100`, respectively), and the result of the operation is `0x00000500`. This is what is being passed into `glClear` - a single number, not multiple arguments.

One can use `&` (bit-AND) operator to tease out bits out of integers. E.g.

```
WRITE = 1
READ = 2
FORCE = 4
def my_method(code)
  puts "write" if code & WRITE != 0
  puts "read" if code & READ != 0
  puts "force" if code & FORCE != 0
end

my_method(READ | FORCE)
# => read
# => force
```

This is not very usual in Ruby, as we have better and clearer ways to do similar things (e.g. one might say `my_method(:read, force: true)` is clearer, and it is definitely simpler to use). However, this is pretty standard in C, and Ruby OpenGL is a pretty thin wrapper over the C functions.